# Solving with ODE45 in Matlab with a variable which is timestep dependent.

Tags: matlab, ode

I've been solving a pretty simple set of ODEs which, for a particular case, produce results as I'd expect. The required output is a graph of the 'population' which is just a manipulation of the results output by ODE.

The issue is that I have some variable *del* which must be slowly incremented as time goes on (slowing being on the order of *del_increment/time_increment << Omega^2*, where Omega is set to 1).  I can happily produce what I've been calling the 'static' case where I have a for loop incrementing del outside of ode45, however this is really just the solution for a static del value over a time period.

I'm struggling to see how I can have ODE45 increment del values [between a max and min] within the function as I have the restriction of small changes of del with time. This would show one plot, displaying small oscillations at zero population and a gradual increase to population =1, as opposed to my current multiple plots for each particular *del* value.

I've given what I've written below, and I hope this explanation makes sense.

```
del=-10:0.1:10; %start at large minus, with some small increment 
Omega=1;

tmax=10; %integration time

for ret=1:length(del)

 y=[0 0 1];  % starting conditions


 [t,y]=ode45(@(t,y) psfour(t,y,del(ret)),[0 tmax],y);


 plot(t,y(:,1))    % plot of one of the solutions 
 axis([0 max(t) -1 1])


 p_11=0.5*(1+y(:,3)); %calculation of the population of an energy level

 figure(2)
 plot(t,p_11)
 axis([0 max(t) 0 1])
 pause(0.05)  % asthetic pause so I can see results 
end
```

and my function

```
function dydt = react(t,y,del)

dydt = zeros(size(y));

Omega=1;
A = y(1); 
B = y(2); 
C = y(3);



dydt(1) = del*B;
dydt(2) = -del*A + Omega*C;
dydt(3) = -Omega*B;

% del=del + Omega*t;

end
```

Comment: The derivative function has the current time as an input, it's the `t` in `react(t,y,del)`. So just use that as the time value at each step, and make a simple function for `del`, inside the derivative function.

Comment: It worked! I must have been having a brain fart. Thanks for the help David :)

Comment: I don't know what your end goal is, but what you're trying to do with `ode45` is probably a bad idea. Your integration function `react` may be called multiple times for a given time step (e.g., for failed steps). The values of `t` passed into `react` aren't even guaranteed to monotonically increase as far as I can recall. You should implement your own fixed step-size Runge-Kutta scheme to do what you suggest. Or your own adaptive scheme where you can reliably access the step size. However, I'd guess that there's another, proper way to solve your problem that avoids all of this.